# C function to swap 2 lines in a text file given their index

Tags: c, file, pointers, swap

I need to write a function that will swap pth record and qth record in the file. The filename, p and q must be passed to this function.

The text file data is based of a Struct that Emulates A Student(name, Student Id, GPA) and is generally going to look like this:

```
Derrek 123 4.00
Egg 234 3.00
Banana 345 2.00
Griffen 456 1.00
Lucas 987 2.00
```

I've looked at a ton of forums and tutorials and it seems as though I need to read through the entire file if I don't know the length of each line.

Is it possible to:
 1.) Read 2 whole lines from a file by index without reading the entire file
 2.) Swap these 2 lines and write them to the file?

Otherwise I have this Spaghetti mess where I'd like to know how to:
1.) Read the whole text file (This appears to be working)
2.) Find the rows I want and store them in a char My code seems to just grab the length of the String. I want it to store the whole String.
3.) Swap these 2 string values. I tried using pointers. I'm fairly confident I'm doing this wrong.
4.) Write these 2 string values to their indexes in the file. For this part is it possible to write just p and q to the file given their known indexes? Or do I have to Iterate through the Entire file again?

```
//Switch Function 
struct Student switchRecords(char filename, int p, int q){
    //Declare Variables
    int c = 0, temp;
    char pText, qText;


    //Open file
    //Read p and q from file
    //Store P and q into temporary variables
    FILE *fp2 = fopen("student.db", "r");
    //Error check
    if(fp2 != NULL){
        char line[252];//max line size
        while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp2) != NULL){
            if(c == p){
                pText = puts(line);
                c++;
            }
            else if(c == q){
                qText = puts(line);
                c++;
            }
            else{
                c++;
            }
        }
        fclose(fp2);
    }
    else{
        printf("Error, File doesn't exist.");
    }

    //Gets real spaghettii about here
    int* pp = pText;
    int* qp = qText;


    printf("P value b: %d\n", pText);   
    printf("Q value b: %d\n", qText);   
    printf("Pp value b: %d\n", pp); 
    printf("Qp value b: %d\n", qp);
    //Swap
    temp = *pp;
    *pp = *qp;
    *qp = temp;

    printf("P value a: %d\n", pText);   
    printf("Q value a: %d\n", qText);
    printf("Pp value a: %d\n", pp); 
    printf("Qp value a: %d\n", qp); 
//p = p p^q
//q = p p^q
//p = p p^q
//Write to file - TODO!  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are mixed the char and char* type.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//Switch Function
void switchRecords(char* filename, int p, int q){
    //Declare Variables
    int c = 0, temp;
    char pText[252], qText[252];
    FILE* fp1, *fp2;

    //Open file
    //Read p and q from file
    //Store P and q into temporary variables
    fp2 = fopen("student.db", "r");
    //Error check
    if(fp2 != NULL){
        temp=0;
        char line[252];//max line size
        while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp2) != NULL){
            if(c == p){
                strcpy(pText,line);
                ++temp;
            }
            else if(c == q){
                strcpy(qText, line);
                ++temp;
            }
            c++;
            if (temp==2) break; //because we have got the two lines!
        }  
        fclose(fp2);
    } 
    else{
        printf("Error, File doesn't exist.");
    }


    //Write to file - TODO!
    fp1 = fopen("student.db.new","w");
    fp2 = fopen("student.db", "r");
    c = 0;
    if(fp1 != NULL && fp2 != NULL){
        char line[252];//max line size
        while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp2) != NULL){
            if(c == p){
                fputs(qText, fp1);
            }
            else if(c == q){
                fputs(pText, fp1);
            }
            else{
                fputs(line, fp1);
            }
            c++;
        }
        fclose(fp1);
        fclose(fp2);
    }
    else{
        printf("Error, File create error.");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    switchRecords("input.txt", 2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```